# How can I optimize my ReactNative Table component to only render changed rows?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a survey app and need to display a whole lot of Radio Buttons.
I'm working with react native and use the react native paper library for my table to render.

In general my component works. Every time a user presses a Radiobutton a state update occurs and the updated state is reflected correctly in the UI by setting the pressed button to "checked" and all other Radiobuttons in that same row to "unchecked".

However, everytime a user presses a button in a row all other rows get re-rendered as well, even though they would not need to be re-rendered because rows never interact with eachother.
This is not a problem when only 3 rows are added to table. But the rendering gets slower the more rows you add to the table and it is already noticeable when 10 rows are added.

I have tried to play around with `useCallback` and `memo` but can't seem to get my head around doing it right.
In the code below I have intentionally removed all useCallback and memo usages to provide a "clean" starting point, since I didn't get any improvements with my tryouts.

**How can I optimize my Component to only re-render the row in which a user pressed a RadioButton?**

These are the interfaces for `Subcategory` and `Score`:

```
export interface Subcategory {
    name: string,
    scores: Score[]
}

export interface Score {
    attribute: string,
    value: string,
}
```

Here is the Grid component with its subcomponents:

```
// @flow
import React, {FunctionComponent} from 'react';
import {DataTable, RadioButton, Text} from "react-native-paper";
import {Score, Subcategory} from "../models/Scorecard";

interface MultipleChoiceGridProps {
    rows: Subcategory,
    possibleValues: string[],
    onTableChange: (newScore: Score) => void
};


interface MultipleChoiceGridCellProps {
    value: string,
    actualValue: string,
    onPress: (newValue: string) => void,
}

interface MultipleChoiceGridRowProps {
    score: Score,
    possibleValues: string[],
    onRowChange:  (newScore: Score) => void
}



const MultipleChoiceGridCell:FunctionComponent<MultipleChoiceGridCellProps> = ({value, actualValue, onPress}) => {
    return (
        <DataTable.Cell>
            <RadioButton status={actualValue === value ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                         onPress={() => onPress(value)}
                         value={value}/>
        </DataTable.Cell>
    )
}

const MultipleChoiceGridRow:FunctionComponent<MultipleChoiceGridRowProps> = ({score, possibleValues, onRowChange}) => {
    console.log("-------rendering row: ", score.attribute);

    const handleCellPress = (value: string) => {
        onRowChange({...score, value})
    }

    return (
        <DataTable.Row>
            <DataTable.Cell key={score.attribute}><Text variant="bodyMedium">{score.attribute}</Text></DataTable.Cell>
            {possibleValues.map(val =>
                <MultipleChoiceGridCell key={score.attribute + "_" + val} value={val} actualValue={score.value} onPress={handleCellPress} />
            )}
        </DataTable.Row>
    )
}

const MultipleChoiceGrid: FunctionComponent<MultipleChoiceGridProps> = ({rows,possibleValues, onTableChange}) => {
    console.log("+++++++++ rendering table +++++++++++")
    return (
            <DataTable>
                <DataTable.Header>
                    <DataTable.Title key={"header"}>{}</DataTable.Title>
                    {possibleValues.map(header => <DataTable.Title key={header}><Text
                        variant={"bodyMedium"}>{header}</Text></DataTable.Title>)}
                </DataTable.Header>
                {rows.scores.sort((a, b) => a.attribute.localeCompare(b.attribute)).map(score =>
                    <MultipleChoiceGridRow key={score.attribute} score={score} possibleValues={possibleValues} onRowChange={(newScore) => onTableChange(newScore)}/>)}
            </DataTable>
    );
};

export default MultipleChoiceGrid
```

This is the demo screen component providing a minimal setup:

```
// @flow
import React, {FunctionComponent, useState} from 'react';
import {View} from "react-native";
import MultipleChoiceGrid from "../components/MultipleChoiceGrid";
import {Score, Subcategory} from "../models/Scorecard";

interface MultipleChoiceGridDemo {
};

const INITIAL_STATE =
    {
        name: "Demo",
        scores: [
            {attribute: "row1", value: ""},
            {attribute: "row2", value: ""},
            {attribute: "row3", value: ""},
            {attribute: "row4", value: ""},
            {attribute: "row5", value: ""},
        ]
    }


const MultipleChoiceGridDemo: FunctionComponent<MultipleChoiceGridDemo> = ({navigation}) => {
    const [subcategory, setSubcategory] = useState<Subcategory>(INITIAL_STATE)


    const handleScoreUpdate = (newScore: Score) => {
        const updated = subcategory.scores.filter(s => s.attribute !== newScore.attribute);
        updated.push(newScore);
        setSubcategory({name: subcategory.name, scores: updated})
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <MultipleChoiceGrid rows={subcategory} possibleValues={["very good", "good", "poor"]} onTableChange={handleScoreUpdate}/>
        </View>
    );
};

export default MultipleChoiceGridDemo
```

Wrapping `handleScoreUpdate` in useCallback won't prevent all rows from rendering because I'd have to provide the whole `subcategory` state as a dependency which changes on every RadioButton press.

It's working kind of smooth with only 5 rows. But in reality I'll have 10+ rows, which causes a noticeable performance decrease for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve my problem.

I approached the solution in multiple steps:

1. I separated the data needed for rendering the form from the actual state that will hold the form values.
   `ScorecardTemplate` holds the information on what to render (form controls, tables, ...) whereas the `formValues` reducer holds the data entered into the form.
2. I moved the state for holding a row's current value into the row. By moving the state close to the component, only the row component has to re-render, when a RadioButton was pressed.
3. To transport the changed value up to the parent, I introduced callback properties up to the `MultipleChoiceGrid`. Since the components in line don't have state, they will not re-render (unless the parent re-renders) and thus the callback references used as properties for the child components do not change.
4. As mentioned in 1. I introduced a `formValues` reducer for holding the actual form data. I hand the `dispatch` down to the `MultipleChoiceGrid` component instead of a callback property. Since react guarantees that the identity of `dispatch` is stable, I'm now able to `memo` the `MultipleChoiceGrid` component and prevent it (and all its children except the row that really changed) from re-rendering.

Here is the code with a pretty big form, much like I'll encounter in production:
(If you want to try it out, you need to replace the `name` constants with some strings)

I know that it's not really elegant to hand `dispatch` into a component like I did. But for handing it down a single level I didn't feel like introducing a context.

```
// @flow
import React, {FunctionComponent, memo, useReducer, useState} from 'react';
import {ScrollView} from "react-native";
import {AttributeTemplate, ScorecardTemplate, SubcategoryTemplate} from "../models/ScorecardTemplate";
import {DefaultCategories, Subcategories} from "../utils/ScorecardUtils";
import {DataTable, RadioButton, Surface, Text} from "react-native-paper";

interface MultipleChoiceGridDemoProps {
};

const demoValues = ["very good", "good", "poor"];

const template: ScorecardTemplate = {
    categories: [
        {
            name: DefaultCategories.FIBER_JUDGE,
            subcategories: [{
                name: Subcategories.FIBER_JUDGE,
                possibleValues: demoValues,
                attributes: [
                    {name: "Micron for Age"},
                    {name: "Density"},
                    {name: "Uniformity of Micron"},
                    {name: "Size of Blanket for Age"},
                    {name: "Handle"},
                    {name: "Absence of Guard Hairs"},
                    {name: "Stable Type"},
                    {name: "Staple Uniformity"},
                    {name: "Staple Length"},
                    {name: "Uniformity of Length"},
                    {name: "Uniformity of Color"},
                    {name: "Brightness"}]
            }]
        },
        {
            name: DefaultCategories.PHENOTYPE,
            subcategories: [
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "Proportions"},
                        {name: "Body Capacity"},
                        {name: "Gait"},
                        {name: "Back (Lordosis/Kyhposis},"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.COVERAGE
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [{name: "Substance of Bones"}],
                    name: Subcategories.SUBSTANCE_OF_BONES
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "Proportions"},
                        {name: "Body Capacity"},
                        {name: "Gait"},
                        {name: "Back (Lordosis/Kyhposis},"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.OVERVIEW
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "X"},
                        {name: "O"},
                        {name: "Base Wide"},
                        {name: "Base Narrow"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.FRONTLEGS_FRONT_VIEW
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "X"},
                        {name: "Base Wide"},
                        {name: "Base Narrow"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.HINDLEGS_BACK_VIEW
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "Sickle Hocks"},
                        {name: "Post Legged"},
                        {name: "Champ Behind"},
                        {name: "Champ Forward"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.HINDLEGS_SIDE_VIEW
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "Down in Pastern"},
                        {name: "Angle too Small"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.FEET
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "True to Type"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.HEAD
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "Wryface"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.JAW
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "Over/Underbite"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.TEETH
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "Other Faults"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.TEETH_OTHER
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "Crucked Tail"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.TAIL
                },
                {
                    possibleValues: demoValues,
                    attributes: [
                        {name: "Note"},
                    ],
                    name: Subcategories.ADDITIONAL_NOTES
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}


interface SubcategoryHeaderProps {
    possibleValues: string[]
}

interface MultipleChoiceGridProps {
    category: string,
    dispatch: any,
    template: SubcategoryTemplate
}

interface MultipleChoiceGridRowsProps {
    attributes: AttributeTemplate[],
    possibleValues: string[],
    onAttributeValueChange: (attribute: string, value: string) => void
}

interface MultipleChoiceGridRowProps {
    possibleValues: string[],
    rowName: string,
    onValueChange: (value: string) => void
}

const MultipleChoiceGridHeader: FunctionComponent<SubcategoryHeaderProps> = ({possibleValues}) => {
    return (
        <DataTable.Header>
            <DataTable.Title key={"attributes"}>{}</DataTable.Title>
            {possibleValues.map(value => <DataTable.Title key={value}><Text>{value}</Text></DataTable.Title>)}
        </DataTable.Header>
    )
}

const MultipleChoiceGridRow: FunctionComponent<MultipleChoiceGridRowProps> = ({
                                                                                  rowName,
                                                                                  possibleValues,
                                                                                  onValueChange
                                                                              }) => {
    console.log("+++ rendering row ", rowName);
    const [actualValue, setActualValue] = useState<string>("")

    const handleRadioButtonPress = (value: string) => {
        setActualValue(value);
        onValueChange(value);
    }

    return (
        <DataTable.Row>
            <DataTable.Cell><Text variant="bodyMedium">{rowName}</Text></DataTable.Cell>
            {possibleValues.map(value =>
                <DataTable.Cell key={value}>
                    <RadioButton status={actualValue === value ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                                 onPress={() => handleRadioButtonPress(value)}
                                 value={value}/>
                </DataTable.Cell>)}
        </DataTable.Row>
    )
}

const MultipleChoiceGridRows: FunctionComponent<MultipleChoiceGridRowsProps> = ({
                                                                                    possibleValues,
                                                                                    attributes,
                                                                                    onAttributeValueChange
                                                                                }) => {
    console.log("++++++ rendering rows")
    return (
        <>
            {attributes.map(attribute =>
                <MultipleChoiceGridRow key={attribute.name}
                                       possibleValues={possibleValues}
                                       rowName={attribute.name}
                                       onValueChange={(value) => onAttributeValueChange(attribute.name, value)}/>
            )}
        </>
    )
}

const MultipleChoiceGrid: FunctionComponent<MultipleChoiceGridProps> = memo(({category, dispatch, template}) => {
    console.log("+++++++++ rendering table +++++++++++++++")

    const handleAttributeValueChange = (attribute: string, value: string) => {
        dispatch({type: "update", payload: {category, subcategory: template.name, attribute, value}});
    }

    return (
        <DataTable>
            <MultipleChoiceGridHeader possibleValues={template.possibleValues}/>
            <MultipleChoiceGridRows
                onAttributeValueChange={handleAttributeValueChange}
                possibleValues={template.possibleValues}
                attributes={template.attributes.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))}/>
        </DataTable>
    )
})


interface ScorecardFormValue {
    category: string,
    subcategory: string,
    attribute: string,
    value: string
}

type FormValuesAction = {
    type: "update",
    payload: ScorecardFormValue
}

const formValuesReducer = (state: ScorecardFormValue[], action: FormValuesAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "update":
            const newValue = action.payload;
            const updated = state.filter(fv => !(fv.value === newValue.value && fv.attribute === newValue.attribute && fv.subcategory === newValue.subcategory && fv.category === newValue.category));
            updated.push(newValue);
            return updated;
    }
}

const MultipleChoiceGridDemo: FunctionComponent<MultipleChoiceGridDemoProps> = ({navigation}) => {
    console.log("*/*/*/*/*/*/*/ RENDERING PARENT */*/*/*/*/*/")
    const [formValues, dispatch] = useReducer(formValuesReducer, []);

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            {template.categories.map(category =>
                <Surface key={category.name}>
                    <Text variant="bodyLarge">{category.name}</Text>
                    {category.subcategories.map(subcategory =>
                        <MultipleChoiceGrid category={category.name} key={subcategory.name} template={subcategory}
                                            dispatch={dispatch}/>
                    )}
                </Surface>
            )}
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

export default MultipleChoiceGridDemo
```

And here are the interfaces for the form Template:

```
export interface AttributeTemplate {
    name: string
}

export interface SubcategoryTemplate {
    name: string,
    possibleValues: string[], //possible values that apply to all attributes in that subcategory
    attributes: AttributeTemplate[]
}

export interface CategoryTemplate {
    name: string,
    subcategories: SubcategoryTemplate[]
}

export interface ScorecardTemplate {
    categories: CategoryTemplate[],
}
```